# Read Value from a list in another list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

i'd like to know how to read out values from a list like that:

```
fragen = [["Frage?",{"ValueOne": 1, "ValueTwo": 0, "ValueThree": 0, "ValueFour": 5}]]
```

i'm a complete beginner in python, any help would be kind.

Originally, it looked like that:

```
fragen = []

fragen.append(["Frage?",
{"ValueOne": 1, "ValueTwo": 0, "ValueThree": 0, "ValueFour": 5}])
```

and i tried to call the Value like that

```
fragen[0][1][0]
```

It doesn't work like that, it gives me an

```
KeyError: 0
```

Thank you for the help, have a nice day.

Comment: What do you expect `fragen[0][1][0]` to print?

Comment: you are trying to access an element of the dictionary as a list item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fragen` is a list of lists. The inner list happen to contain a string and a dictionary.

`fragen[0]` returns the inner list, ie `["Frage?",{"ValueOne": 1, "ValueTwo": 0, "ValueThree": 0, "ValueFour": 5}]`.

`fragen[0][1]` returns the dictionary, ie `{"ValueOne": 1, "ValueTwo": 0, "ValueThree": 0, "ValueFour": 5}`.

`fragen[0][1]['ValueOne']` will return the value associated with the key `'ValueOne'` from that dictionary, ie `1`.

You can access the different keys in the dictionary in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

The list contains string and [dictionary](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html) data types.

You want to try using

`fragen[0][1]['ValueOne']` to print 1.

This is how you access dictionaries in Python.

Answer (score 0):

@DeepSpace has already answered your question . but for future reference and easier access for multidimensional arrays

you could use

```
import numpy
fragen=numpy.ndarray((x,y,z,..))
```

x,y,z are dimensions of your n dimensional array